# Can I have a non-jar-based library project using Eclipse with ADT r14?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am working with a complex library that, for historical reasons, is separated into two Android library projects that reference each other. Prior to r14 of the SDK, this worked fine. Each simply referred to the other's source code. We released a jar, and in Eclipse, applications could refer to the two library projects.

With r14, Eclipse tries to build a separate jar from each one. Since each references the other, they both fail. It may be necessary to construct a single new library project from the two. But that's development work and presents other problems. For now, I'd like to instruct Eclipse and ADT to handle them as before, i.e. not to build jars from them, just to reference the source. I've been digging, but I haven't yet found a way to do that.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is probably no. We worked around it using source links, which improves matters tremendously. This mechanism didn't work with previous ADT versions.

Answer (score 0):

The other solution that would work is using apklib project that you create with the android maven plugin.